# How to convert the multiclass semantic segmentation mask in PNG format to COCO JSON format?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, dataset, semantic-segmentation

I know, it can be done via opencv find.contours, etc.
But maybe there is a ready-made solution that works with several classes?